# Completely remove an earlier commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset

Consider the following commit history:

```
* 627f412 (HEAD -> master) final commit
* 1425cf8 added some file
* 2c8bb78 initial commit
```

The repository is neither pushed not pulled during these commits.

The second commit 1425cf8 is an unnecessary commit. And I want to completely remove that commit.

So, the new log will look like:

```
* 627f412 (HEAD -> master) final commit
* 2c8bb78 initial commit
```

How do I achieve that?

Is `git reset --hard HEAD~1` the correct thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is git reset --hard HEAD~1 the correct thing to do in this situation?

No: `git rebase -i 2c8bb78` is.

You can drop the extra commit in the interactive rebase session. (if you want to drop completely what 1425cf8 introduced)
Or you can squash the two commits.

For that, in the interactive session (see "[Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)"):

- add a `s` for squash in front of 627f412

Note the end result will *not* be 627f412: the new commit will have a different SHA1, as its content will differ.

Comment: VonC Here is what happens when I `git rebase -i 2c8bb78`.

An editor window opens. with the following:

pick 1425cf8 added some files                                                                                           
pick 627f412 final commit

I deleted the first line. Saved the file.

This results in:

error: could not apply 627f412... final commit

Am I doing something wrong?

I have git rebase --abort to get back to original status

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History: do you want to drop 1425cf8 changes, or squash them with 627f412?

Comment: VonC either. It is a commit that should not have been. Moreover, the 627f412 commit is what I want and it includes everything that was part of 1425cf8 anyway

Comment: @deshmukh OK. Lt's start with squash then: see my edited answer.

Comment: VonC, I did as per your modified answer. But, no luck. It produces exactly the same error as in my first comment. And I did the abort thing again to get things in original shape.

Comment: @deshmukh If 627f412 modifying files that were introduced by 1425cf8?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124268/discussion-between-deshmukh-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

You can reset (without `--hard`!) your HEAD to `2c8bb78` and then commit the changes.
Or rebase on 2c8bb78 and squash to two other commits (`627f412` and `1425cf8`).

With `reset --hard`, you might lose your modifications.

Comment: user4780495 I seem to be on a shaky ground. See my comment on @VonC's VonC's answer.

To make things simpler, could you please elaborate on the answer?